# Navigation Bar title font does not change

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

Following another SO question, I am trying to change the navigationBar title font using the following piece of code in the viewDidLoad method:

```
  NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                           [UIColor colorWithRed:21.0/255.0 green:62.0/255.0 blue:111.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                           shadow, NSShadowAttributeName,
                                                           [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack" size:21.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];
```

But the font is not changing.

Can you please tell me what is wrong there?

Comment: Where do you have that code ? Put it to your AppDelegate before showing any views

Comment: Thank you @GrzegorzKrukowski, putting the code in the AppDelegate solves the issue.  Would you mind writtin your comment in an answer to let me mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change UIAppearance attributes anywhere outside of `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` in your App Delegate. UIAppearance is designed to be changed when the app starts.

If you move it to `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` in your delegate it should work.